# Getting AppleEvent's in Qt/Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, qt, qt4

I have some Qt 4.4/Carbon code that works fine for getting Mac OS X document open events (e.g. user double clicks on document associated with app):

```
#ifdef Q_OS_MACX
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
#endif

MyApplication::MyApplication( int& argc, char** argv )
:QApplication( argc, argv )
{
#ifdef Q_OS_MACX
    AEInstallEventHandler( kCoreEventClass, kAEOpenDocuments,
     TPApplication::appleEventHandler, 0, false );
#endif
}

MyApplication::~MyApplication()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_MACX
    AERemoveEventHandler( kCoreEventClass, kAEOpenDocuments,
     TPApplication::appleEventHandler, false );
#endif
}

#ifdef Q_OS_MACX
OSErr 
TPApplication::appleEventHandler( const AppleEvent* ae, AppleEvent*, long )
{
    // process events
}
#endif
```

I want to port this code to Qt 4.7/Cocoa. Is it still possible to call this code from a Cocoa based Qt app, or do I have to call the Cocoa API instead? Or is there are more elegant way to intercept the user double clicking on a document associated with the app without platform specific code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. I'm not sure but i think it did work. But take a look at it from different side. Why keep legacy code? Carbon API is not 64 bit. Migration of this code shouldn't be hard (check NSAppleEventManager).

This is how you register:

```
NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
[appleEventManager setEventHandler:self
                       andSelector:@selector(handleEvent:withReplyEvent:)
                     forEventClass:kCoreEventClass
                        andEventID:kAEOpenDocuments];
```

And this is method

- (void)handleEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent: (NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
  {
  }

Remember that you will have to export Cocoa code to another file (best would be .mm), but still you can use your C++/Qt code inside of that file without any problem.